# how to count versions in one cell by using HBase Shell?

Tags: hbase

If I set 100 version for HBase column family `f1`.

I put some data(I don't know how many) into the same rowkey(eg: `r1`) and same cell `f1:c1`.

now, I want know how many data I put to `r1`,`f1:c1`, I want count current the numbers of versions in `r1`,`f1:c1` cell by using **HBase Shell**.